# How to create a WS-Trust client using JAX-RS usin Apache CXF library?

Tags: java, web-services, spring-boot, cxf, ws-trust

I searched through lots of documentation and googled a lot in order to find how to create a `WS-Trust client` using JAX-RS  using `Apache CXF library`?

Apache documentation clearly mentions that it support WS-Trust authentication but Partially.

My question is how to create a WS-Trust client using JAX-RS  using Apache CXF library?

Do we have any sample project or good documentation reference for same?

Comment: Looking for the same!

Comment: @UjjwalGulecha you could upvote and/or add some bounty and share the question on FB and twitter etc :)